# Identity to break up a shift in a Heaviside Step Function

Tags: number-theory, functions, step-function

$H(x)$ is defined as the Heaviside step function, so $H(x) =  \Bigg\lbrace\begin{array}{ll}
      1 & x > 0 \\
      0 & x \leq 0
      \end{array}$

The case for $H(0) = 0$ matters for me.

I have the function $H(x+y)$ nested in a product. I need to break up $H(x+y)$ to simplify my overall function further. I know that $H(x+y) \neq H(x) + H(y)$, is there any identity that I can use to break up $H(x+y)$? I have been stumped for hours on this.

Comment: Your question is incomplete (e.g., you do not provide an expression for the "overall function" that needs to be simplified), but if you replace $x$ with $x+y$ in the definition of $H(x)$, you will get the `definition' of $H(x+y)$. The two cases to consider are $y > -x$ and $y \leq -x$. The only nonzero contribution comes from the region $y > -x$. (I assume you have no derivatives acting on the step function in the expression not provided...)

Comment: @leastaction i'm asking for a general identity for H(x+y) if there exists one. If there does not i will follow up with a different question for the overall function. I would like to try to solve the overall on my own first, I am just stuck on ways to manipulate the Heaviside function.

Comment: This may not be a good idea for a general domain of definition, but have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Other_expressions?

Comment: @leastaction yes I have. I am beginning to think there is a clean identity to break it up since i seems like a shifted heaviside function is almost atomic in nature (i.e not a basic unti), but i may be wrong.

Comment: @yosmo78 Why have you marked this question as "number theory"? Is there a connection to number theory? I ask in case it is helpful for answering.

Comment: Are there any conditions for $x$ and $y$? If not then we will have to make cases I suppose.  There will be 6 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only identity that you can use is
$$H(ax)=H(x)\quad,\quad a\in\mathbb R$$
So you can do
$$H(x+y)=H\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)$$
then, you can use linear transform (actually rotating by $45$ degree:
$$x=\frac{u-v}{\sqrt2}\quad,\quad y=\frac{u+v}{\sqrt2}$$
which will change
$$H(x+y)=H\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)=H(u)$$
But, be sure to apply the same tranform to the rest of your system.